# Implementing inline editing for a web order form without using Javascript

Tags: html, css, forms

As the title states, I'm trying to find a good solution to implement inline editing for a web order form with just HTML/CSS.

The only mediocre solution I have right now is this -> http://jsfiddle.net/jmggp/1/

But I think it looks unprofessional. Are there any other solutions that I can try to learn about?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inline editing"? Your example looks like a standard HTML form with individual fields (without labels)?

Comment: You are using the placeholder attribute for your forms, these can be styled with CSS too, but it's not compatible with all browsers. Take a look at [this site](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css).

Comment: sorry to be more clear, I mean inline editing like this -> http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid/inline_editing @w3d

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll **have to rely on JavaScript** if you plan on serving the same possibilities for all the browsers your visitors would be using. It is possible to do it without JS using HTML5 but then you have the problem of requiring modern browsers.

To take a look at inline editing using HTML5 I recommend you take a look at: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but inline editing requires JavaScript - the HTML/CSS of a page cannot be changed without it. The HTML is the content that your webserver sends to your visitor's browser; it is static. The CSS (also static) tells the browser how to display the content. In order to change the content *after it reaches the browser* (as in editing), you have to use JavaScript.